# Creating clustered index in mysql for hierarchical table

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing

I have a hierarchical relation without any limited depth, every row will have a parent row specified in a column.
Most of the queries will be against that parent key only. So I am thinking to declare parent field as clustered index so that my queries can run fast. But the problem is table will have frequent insert and delete operations.
As far I know clustered index fields are sorted and point to data location on disk and all non-clustered index uses reference from clustered index  only. So frequent insert operations should be costly I guess. So what should I do ? Is it fine to declare parent field as clustered index ?

Answer (score 1):

The `PRIMARY KEY` is the only "clustered" index available in MySQL.  But the PK is `UNIQUE`.  So, `parent_id` cannot be the clustered index, at least not by itself...

`PRIMARY KEY(parent_id, id)` would work.  You get the "clustering" effect of having `parent_id` as the first part, and you get `UNIQUE` by including the `id`.  I am assuming `id` would otherwise be the PK for the table, and each "item" is uniquely identified by `id`.

But wait, you declared `id` to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  Then add `INDEX(id)`; that will suffice.

To find all the 'children' of $parent:

```
SELECT ... WHERE parent_id = $parent ...
```

All the children will be "clustered next to each other" in the table, thereby efficient to fetch.  The grandchildren, on the other hand will be elsewhere.

To find one's parent:

```
SELECT parent_id FROM tbl WHERE id = $me
```

To get info about one's parent, do a "self join":

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM tbl c
    JOIN tbl p  ON p.id = c.parent_id
    WHERE c.id = $me
```

To derive all the ancestors or all the descendants, it is probably best to use application code with a loop doing enough SELECTs to traverse the tree upward or downward.